# Sequelize Model not syncing after Migration

Tags: javascript, migration, sequelize.js

I am able to successfully `bulkCreate` on a sequelize model.

I ran a migration to add a column called `utc_offset` to that model which worked.

The issue I am running into is that after I reset my express server, the model in my files does not seem to have the new column when trying to create new instances. The DB is showing its there, but when I pass in a value to that column, it does not add the value for the new column `utc_offset`.

I believe it has something to do with `db.sequelize.sync()` - When I set he options to `{force: true}` it deleted the model and would not re-create it.

Below is my code:

Server:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    api,
    db = require('./models');

api = app.listen(config.address.port, config.address.host, function () {
    var host = api.address().address,
        port = api.address().port

    console.log('API listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
    db.sequelize.sync();
});
```

index.js in my `models` folder
'use strict';

```
var fs        = require('fs');
var path      = require('path');
var cls       = require('continuation-local-storage');
var namespace = cls.createNamespace('ss-transaction');
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
Sequelize.cls = namespace;
var basename  = path.basename(module.filename);
var env       = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
var config    = require('../config/config.js');
var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.db.database, config.db.username, config.db.password, {
    host: config.db.host,
    dialect: config.db.dialect,
    define: {underscored: true}
});
var db        = {};

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(function(file) {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename);
  })
  .forEach(function(file) {
    if (file.slice(-3) !== '.js') return;
    var model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(function(modelName) {
  if ('associate' in db[modelName]) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

'lessons' model:

```
"use strict";

module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {

    var Lesson = sequelize.define("Lesson", {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        title: DataTypes.STRING,

    }, {
        tableName: "lessons",
    });

    return Lesson;
};
```

'use strict';

```
module.exports = {
    up: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
        return queryInterface.addColumn(
            'lessons',
            'utc_offset',
            Sequelize.INTEGER
        );
    },

    down: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
        return queryInterface.removeColumn(
            'lessons',
            'utc_offset'
        );
    }
};
```

BulkCreate

```
var lessons = [{title: "lessonA", utc_offest: 1},{title: "lessonB", utc_offest: 9}]

    Lesson.bulkCreate(lessons)
        .then(function () {
            res.sendStatus(201);
        });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Migrations will only change the table structure in the DB - you have to manually add the utc_offset column to the model

Comment: So whenever I want to do a migration I need to do two things.

1. Create a migration file and run the migration
2. Modify the model according to the migration file/changes I would like implemented?